# select tag has no option

Tags: html, angular

In my angular2 app, I have tried to set option of the a select tag using an array in a component.

Here is the select tag:

```
 <select 
                class="form-control" 
                ngControl="frequency" 
                #frequency="ngForm" 
                required>
                <div *ngFor="#f of frequencies">
                    <option >{{f}}</option>
                </div>
            </select>
```

Iand here is the component:

```
export class FormComponent{

    frequencies=['aaa','bbb','ccc'];

}
```

The problem, when the page get loaded it has none of these option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the `*ngFor` on the `<option>` element and remove the `<div>`

```
        <select 
            class="form-control" 
            ngControl="frequency" 
            #frequency="ngForm" 
            required>
                <option *ngFor="#f of frequencies">{{f}}</option>
        </select>
```

In recent Angular2 versions it should be

```
        <select 
            class="form-control" 
            ngControl="frequency" 
            #frequency="ngForm" 
            required>
                <option *ngFor="let f of frequencies">{{f}}</option>
        </select>
```

(`let` instead of `#`)

Comment: By default the text passed to option (`{{f}}`) is used as value AFAIK, therefore it shouldn't necessary (depends on what he wants to accomplish exactly).